# OSX : Defining a new URL handler that points straight at a Python script

Tags: python, macos, url, handler

I'm trying to define a new URL handler under OSX that will point at a python script.

I've wrapped the Python script up into an applet (right-clicked on the .py, and gone Open With -> Build Applet)

I've added the following into the applet's Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>Do My Thing</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>dmt</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I've also used the [More Internet preferences pane](http://www.monkeyfood.com/software/moreInternet/) to specify "dmt" as a protocol, but when I try to get it to link the protocol to my applet, it says that "There was a problem setting the app as the helper"

Anyone know where I should go from here?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a lot of messing around, I've managed to get this working under OSX...

This is how I'm doing it:

in the AppleScript Script Editor, write the following script:

```
on open location this_URL
    do shell script "/scripts/runLocalCommand.py '" & this_URL & "'"
end open location
```

If you want to make sure you're running the Python from a certain shell (in my case, I'm using tcsh generally, and have a .tcshrc file that defines some environment variables that I want to have access to) then that middle line might want to be:

```
do shell script "tcsh -c \"/scripts/localCommand.py '" & this_URL & "'\""
```

I was wanting to do all of my actual processing inside a python script - but because of the way URL handers work in OSX, they have to call an application bundle rather than a script, so doing this in AppleScript seemed to be the easiest way to do it.

in the Script Editor, Save As an "Application Bundle"

Find the saved Application Bundle, and Open Contents. Find the Info.plist file, and open it. Add the following:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.mycompany.AppleScript.LocalCommand</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>LocalCommand</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>local</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
```

Just before the last two lines, which should be:

```
</dict>
</plist>
```

There are three strings in there that might want to be changed:

```
com.mycompany.AppleScript.LocalCommand
LocalCommand
local
```

The third of these is the handler ID - so a URL would be local://something

So, then this passes over to the Python script.

This is what I've got for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import urllib
arg = sys.argv[1]
handler, fullPath = arg.split(":", 1)
path, fullArgs = fullPath.split("?", 1)
action = path.strip("/")
args = fullArgs.split("&")
params = {}
for arg in args:
    key, value = map(urllib.unquote, arg.split("=", 1))
    params[key] = value
```

Comment: You could also use py2app to cut out the AppleScript bit, I believe.

Comment: Have you since found an easier way to do this? It seems like quite an involved process still. Further, I'm building a `.app` out of Python that would like to use a custom callback protocol callback for authorization with a web service. Unlike just running a Python script, I expect that an instance of the application is running at the time the protocol call is made. How do I ensure that it gets handled by the opened instance of the application?

Comment: @fatuhoku the application needs to detect that it is already running and forward the request via some sort of ipc.