# Python URL handlers for web browsers

Tags: python, url, browser-extension

How can I use Python to add a handler to a browser, so when someone clicks a link like foo://foobar/ it'll open my program to handle it? Ideally there would be a way to do it cross-platform, but I recognize that OS-specific code will probably be needed.

Comment: Please post what have you tried / or at least searched so far. The idea is not that other people here build stuff for you.

Comment: I've looked through the python standard library and googled for "python custom url handler" and various permutations of it. I'm not asking for someone to build something for me, just a pointer in the right direction so I can build it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GNOME](http://people.w3.org/~dom/archives/2005/09/integrating-a-new-uris-scheme-handler-to-gnome-and-firefox/)

[Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx)

[OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418910/osx-defining-a-new-url-handler-that-points-straight-at-a-python-script)

Comment: Do you know of a solution for KDE?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, why you are looking for OS Specific code. But there is module called [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html), which you are use in your programs as a handler which can open your platform specific browser. Does this help?

Comment: webbrowser is an excellent module, but what he's looking for is a way to dispatch *from* a normal web browser *to* a python program, not the other way around. (not my downvote, btw)

Comment: Okay, I get it. But that could be handled by `subprocess` and sending his program and url as the argument. Let me check what Ignacio pointed out.

Comment: No, he wants a certain "protocol" (like the "foo" in "foo://foobar/") to be automatically handled by a python program in a normal web browsing session. I don't see how a specific *python* module will help you to *launch* python automatically.