# Python script that registers itself as a custom protocol handler on OS X?

Tags: python, macos, url

I am looking for a Python script that is able to register itself as a URL protocol handler (URL handler) under OS X.

The only information I found was http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HowToRegisterURLHandler but this is for Apps written in Objective-C and I'm not sure if how/it's possible to replicate the same with a Python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Use AppleScript as an intermediary, as demonstrated here:

[Python URL Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418910/osx-defining-a-new-url-handler-that-points-straight-at-a-python-script)

The information from the URL is passed into the Python script arguments.

Comment: Have you found any more straight forward ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

if this is your own custom script you'd like to handle (as oppose to something that you want to distribute to more users), you can take a look at LinCastor app (http://onflapp.wordpress.com/lincastor/custom-url-handlers/) it enables you to register custom protocol and handle it using a script.