# Distribute python URL handler

Tags: python, macos, url, pip

I'm working on [a URL handler](https://github.com/deckardai/dcode) for macOS and Linux. It works using the applescript/applet trick similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2499107/6170994).
Now, how to distribute it and let users install it easily?

Currently it's on Pypi, and the package includes the wrapper macOS app. But if [the setup script](https://github.com/deckardai/dcode/blob/setup/dcode/install.py) attempts to open it, the system refuses for pseudo-security reasons. Right now the user has to right-click open in Finder to make it work.

Is there a clean solution to that problem? On Linux, the setup script can just run the update-desktop-database command which is ideal.